# query to search main table and associative table

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to create a search function on my website which searches for keywords in a number of columns in my main table, and also any tags which match those keywords linked via an associative table.

I've got a query which works for the keywords only, and a query which can find 1 tag, but i'm looking to do both in a single query.

Combining my 2 working queries and I came up with this query

```
SELECT * FROM flight_trips
WHERE MATCH (destination_country, destination_city, outbound_airport, return_airport, inbound_airport, accommodation_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND status = ?
UNION
SELECT * FROM flight_trips
INNER JOIN trip_tags ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC
```

$tagsql is built using each keyword and adding `" OR "`

This query fails with the error `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`, which i'm assuming is because the JOIN adds the columns and they don't add up.

I want to be able to search for example "beach alicante" and find all results which match either "beach" or "alicante" in the MATCH clause, and search my `tags` table for "beach" and "alicante", and any records linked to those tags. (beach would be a tag linked to a record, alicante would be in destination_city in the main table).

I cannot get my head around this and would appreciate any help! I've searched and searched but I don't actually know what i'm searching for to find the answer to this.

`flight_trips`

```
INSERT INTO `flight_trips` (`id`, `destination_country`, `destination_city`, `destination_currency`, `outbound_airport`, `airline_depart`, `return_airport`, `airline_return`, `inbound_airport`, `outbound_takeoff`, `outbound_landing`, `inbound_takeoff`, `inbound_landing`, `flight_cost`, `overnight_stay`, `accommodation_cost`, `accommodation_name`, `airport_transfer_type`, `airport_transfer_cost`, `airport_transfer_duration`, `trip_details`, `rating`, `user_name`, `user_email`, `added_timestamp`, `approved_timestamp`, `status`) VALUES
(2, 'Spain', 'Alicante', 'Euro', 'London Gatwick', '', '', '', 'Alicante Airport', 1699423800, 1699429200, 1699481700, 1699487100, 45.00, 0, 0.00, '', 'bus', 8, 60, '', 2, 'Someone', 'someone@email.com', 1699313293, 0, 'approved');
```

`tags` table

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(6, 'beach');
```

Table to link tags with trips

```
INSERT INTO `trip_tags` (`id`, `trip_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 2, 6);
```

Edit: Tried using this new query:

```
SELECT *, NULL as Col1, NULL AS Col2, NULL AS Col3 FROM flight_trips
                WHERE MATCH (destination_country, destination_city, outbound_airport, return_airport, inbound_airport, accommodation_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                AND status = ?
                UNION
                SELECT * FROM trip_tags
                JOIN flight_trips ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC
```

I'm no longer getting an error message and I am getting results, but something is wrong retrieving the data from the columns. I appear to get the correct number of results, but `while($data = $search_info->fetch_assoc()){` and using `$data['column_name']` does not give me the correct information.

How can I correct this?

EDIT: I've figured it's something to do with the dummy columns because my data has shifted 3 columns along. For example, my $data['return_airport'] is "Euro" where as that data belongs in `destination_currency` 3 columns previous. How can I re-align these?

Answer (score 0):

The error means you have different number of columns being returned in the first select then the second select.  You can't union different number of columns and names in a union.

A possible solutions is to add 3 dummy columns to your first union at the end of the *.  By doing this you will also need to declare the columns in the second select.

Example:

```
SELECT *, NULL As trip_tag_id, NULL As Trip_ID, NULL AS Tag_ID FROM flight_trips
WHERE MATCH (destination_country, destination_city, outbound_airport, return_airport, inbound_airport, accommodation_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND status = ?
UNION
SELECT ft.*, T.id AS trip_tag_id, T.Trip_ID, T.Tag_ID  FROM flight_trips ft
INNER JOIN trip_tags T ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I seem to have made progress, but I still can't get it working.

I now get the error:

`Table 'ft' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list`

Comment: Did you put a space or something in there?  "ft" is the alias for the table.

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit on my main post. I'm getting results, but retrieving the data isn't working with the column names

Answer (score 0):

I think i've finally done it! It appears to be working correctly using this query:

```
SELECT *, NULL as Col1, NULL AS Col2, NULL AS Col3 FROM flight_trips
WHERE MATCH (destination_country, destination_city, outbound_airport, return_airport, inbound_airport, accommodation_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND status = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM flight_trips
JOIN trip_tags ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC
```

I had an issue where the data had shifted 3 columns along so it wasn't in the correct columns. This is due to the dummy columns added in the query. My understanding is this happens because in the first SELECT query

`SELECT * FROM trip_tags JOIN flight_trips ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC`

I created 3 dummy columns, but the second SELECT query didn't have those, so the data didn't align causing something like this:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|DUMMY1 | DUMMY2 | DUMMY3 | id | destination_country | destination_city |
|-------|--------|--------|----|---------------------|------------------|
|   1   | France | Paris  | Euro | London Stansted   |     Easyjet      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I swapped trip_tags and flight_trips like so:

`SELECT * FROM flight_trips JOIN trip_tags ON trip_tags.trip_id = flight_trips.id WHERE ".$tagsql." AND flight_trips.status = ? ORDER BY added_timestamp DESC`

Which added the dummy columns to the end, rather than the start, of the dataset, keeping all my "real" data where it was supposed to be.

Comment: In the future, try to not use * in your code.  Try to declare all columns to avoid this sort of error in the future.  If you declare columns, you can easily line up all your columns.